# What place was called [in Latin] Audomaropolitanus?

Tags: latin-language, toponymy

I came across [an old image](https://oldthing.de/Jacobus-Pamelius-Episcopus-Audomaropolitanus-Designatus-Jacques-de-Pamele-1536-1587-Pamelius-Mons-Bruge-0042543075#gallery) of one of my wife's ancestors from the late 16th century, and below it is written

> Jacobus Pamelius, Episcopus Audomaropolitanus designatus

which in English is

> Jacobus Pamelius, appointed Bishop of Audomaropolitanus

Does anyone know the modern name for Audomaropolitanus?

Comment: Nice Roman numerals — old style, not medieval — designating 1587 in the top-right. (|) |) LXXXVII

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Audomaropolitanus is actually the adjectival form, and it means "of Audomaropolis." So you'd want to look for that. Latin Wikipedia identifies it as [Saint-Omer](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanctus_Audomarus), in northern France.

Comment: The inhabitants of Saint-Omer are still called "les Audomarois" nowadays.

Comment: It isn't the genitive form, -anus forms an adjective derived from the place name.

Comment: @SirCornflakes - Gotta admit, the function of the anus was *not* something I expected to get from my Cornflakes this morning.